# Dask DataFrame: write multiple CSV by column

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe

I have a Dask DataFrame with a column `"file"`. I want to write each line of the dataframe to a CSV whose path is given by the `"file"` column.

For instance, on the example below, the row indices 0, 1, 2, and 4 should be written to the file `a.csv` ; while we will write the row 2 to `b.csv` ; and the rows 3 and 5 to `c.csv`:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3, 7, 11, 2], "y": [1, 1, 2, 8, 0, 0], "file": ["a.csv", "a.csv", "b.csv", "c.csv", "a.csv", "c.csv"]})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
```

I tried two solutions that both works but are super slow and make the memory crash (even with `<100MB` chunks and `128GB` of total RAM). The priority right now is to make it less expensive in term of memory, but if you can make it faster then it's even better!

#### Bad solution 1

Get each file group, and right them with a for loop. Super ugly, and super inefficient...

```
for file in ddf["file"].unique().compute():
    ddf[ddf["file"] == file].to_csv(file, single_file=True)
```

#### Bad solution 2

Use `map_partitions` and group datataframe on each partition separately.

```
from pathlib import Path

def _write_partition(df: pd.DataFrame, partition_info=None) -> None:
    if partition_info is not None:
        for file, group_df in df.groupby("file"):
            group_df.to_csv(
                file, mode="a", header=not Path(file).exists(), index=False
            )

ddf.map_partitions(_write_partition).compute()
```

This is working on small examples, but with my big dataframe (`20GB`), it runs for 3 hours without writing even one single line of CSV and then crashes because of memory (even with `128GB` of RAM). I'm quite new to Dask so maybe I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: Hi, what I would do is to use groupby/apply on the dask dataframe, grouping all the rows with the same file column value in a unique partition, and then write it using pandas. However, this will work only if each grouped dataframe fit into memory.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! Yet, in my case, it’s highly possible that one group doesn’t fit into memory…

Comment: In that case, your second approach is probably a good start, but I would use it to write to temporary files for each partition (e.g. something like group_df.to_csv(file + '/' + partition_info['number'] + '.csv'), and then add another step to concatenate the temporary files together. This would avoid race conditions to occur when writing. However, I'm not sure why this approach is giving you memory error.

Comment: Yes indeed I should make sure I don't have issues when different partitions are writting on the same file, thanks for the advice!
Also, I just figured out the issue was due to another `map_partitions` I was doing before this one. I don't understand why it was giving this memory error, but I found another way to do it so this is now fixed :)